# RPM command stuck/FREEZE when installing RPM file

Tags: rpm

I want to install the following rpm from some reason RPM is stuck or freeze and not install the RPM package also I can't stop it by control C,

```
 root]# rpm -Uvh --repackage /var/tmp/bash-2.05b-41.8.i386.rpm
```

OR

```
 root]# rpm -Uvh  /var/tmp/bash-2.05b-41.8.i386.rpm
```